# remove whitespace from xml document using ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nonblank

I have created an XML file with Ruby:

```
xml_file = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.first_node("id" => "12") {
        xml.second_node {
        }
    }
  }
end
```

The output is full of /n and white spaces, like:

```
</first_node id="12">\n      <Second_node>
```

I would like something like:

```
</first_node id="12"><Second_node>
```

I have found something like:

```
string.delete(' '),
```

but in this case it deletes ALL whitespaces, that it is not what I want.
This would be the result:

```
 </first_nodeid="12"><Second_node>
```

This is why I tried using Nokogiri.
I tried something like:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("file_name.xml")) do |config|
  config.strict.noblanks
end
```

but I am not sure, how shall apply the .noblanks to my file? Is there another solution?
Thank you

Comment: Not sure about the second option. But the first option would remove all white space what would certainly break documents. Imagine you have this very basic XML document _<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>_ and remove all white space.

Comment: your full-file string can be accessed with `xml_file.to_xml` from there you can replace/delete what you want. But I would warn you that the string representation is generated automatically and should not be played around too much. 

Lastly, your XML as two `root` node, watch out ;)

Comment: thanks. It actually now deletes all the whitespaces, but I do want some whitespaces, like between "first_node id=...". Any idea about this?

Comment: I have done:
xml_file.to_xml.split.join(" ").gsub("> <","><")
and it seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should give you what you are looking for

```
string.gsub(/\\n/, '').gsub(/>\s*/, ">").gsub(/\s*</, "<")
```